# Rewrite Rule: Question about regex pattern

Tags: asp.net

I can't figure out why a certain rewrite rule does not work.
I have this rule:

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="testsite\.com" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.testsite.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When I go into IIS and using the URL Rewrite module, I tested using "http://testsite.com".  This works.  But after placing an updated web.config in production, these are my results from typing in these into the url:

I was able to reach the site by typing in these variations:

```
https://www.testsite.com
http://www.testsite.com
www.testsite.com
testsite.com
```

But I received the error message "testsite.com refused to connect" when typing in:

```
https://testsite.com
http://testsite.com
```

What am I missing, that is preventing the last 2 from working?  It seems like the rewrite rule I have should catch all requests.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that for the last two examples, their `{HTTP_HOST}` will have no www which means that it will match your condition resulting in your negate attribute skipping your rule action.

I would recommend enabling [IIS Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) in order to identify exactly why your rewrite rule isn't working for those values.